# How to stop a program in Idle, python 3.2

Tags: python

I made a program in Idle that says:

```
for trial in range(3):
if input('Password:') == 'password':
    break
else:
    # didn't find password after 3 attempts
    **I need a stop program here**
print ("Welcome in")
```

Remember, this is in Idle, so I need program for Idle, not CMD. I also am using Python 3.2, if that helps.

Comment: it a `if-else` or `for-else`?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's in IDLE or CMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sys.exit()` or `raise SystemExit`

```
import sys
for trial in range(3):
    if input('Password:') == 'password':
        break
else:
    sys.exit()
print ("Welcome in"))
```

**Edit:**
To end it **silently** wrap it in a `try-except` block:

```
try:
    import sys
    for trial in range(1):
        if raw_input('Password:') == 'password':
            break
    else:
        raise SystemExit #or just sys.exit()
    print ("Welcome in")
except SystemExit:
    pass  #when the program throws SysExit do nothing here,i.e end silently
```

Comment: I get an error saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "F:\password.py", line 8, in <module>

    sys.exit()

SystemExit

Comment: That's expected behavior -- sys.exit() raises SystemExit, which tells Python to terminate the program.

Comment: Use `sys.exit(returnCode)`, where the return code is nonzero for abnormal exiting (usually 1).

Comment: @C0deH4cker indentation fixed.

Comment: Nope, only the first one is fixed. Look at the level your else is on compared to the if. Also, you dont need the else if the if simply returns

Comment: @C0deH4cker look carefully it's a `for-else` loop. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, never use those. Looks ugly to me.

Answer (score 4):

A much nicer way to do this IMHO would be to put your program into a function and `return` when you want it to stop.  Then just call the function to run your program.

```
def main():
    for trial in range(3):
        if input('Password:') == 'password':
            break
    else:
        return
    print ("Welcome in")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what you mean by "in IDLE" vs "in CMD". A Python shell launched by IDLE should be able to be terminated the same way as a Python shell launched from the commandline.

Also, the tabs in your example appear to be wrong: everything below `for...` and above `print...` should be indented.

On to your question: are you asking for a command that terminates your script at that point? If so, adding the two lines `from sys import exit` and then calling `exit()` should do the trick, though it will raise a `SystemExit` exception. If you don't like that, you can add a `pass` handler for the `SystemExit` exception type at the outer layer of your program.

Comment: sometimes, commands in idle are different than in CMD (some things work in idle/cmd that doesn't work in the other.)

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit) can exit a program at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `sys.exit()` and it highlights `'sys'` as `INVALID SYNTAX`.

It might be something to do with how I'm doing it, but if that's the case, then IDK then.